# Karate - Convert entire response from XML to Json

Tags: karate

I am using a soap service and i need to convert the response to Json and print the same. I tried to achieve this like below; but while running, it skips below lines and doesn't convert xml to json. Note that my xml response contains hundreds of parameter. I get proper response for the service but conversion doesn't happen. I can directly use `*json jsonres = response` but just assigning to a variable for easy reading.

```
When soap action 'getResponse' 

* def xmlres = response
* json jsonres = xmlres
* match jsonres == response
* print jsonres

Then match response contains 'Success'
```

Comment: Sorry for the silly questions; But, Im not interested in Java. Trying to learn and implement Karate. In many areas Karate super super easy as i dont have much of coding background and learning on my own. And thanks for developing such a cool framework!

Comment: oh ok. yes, Karate should be perfect for you. but you seem to have started out with a slightly complex XML to JSON conversion situation. still - trying to be un-biased - I don't know of any other tool that makes it easier

Comment: Yeah, but, if this is possible in karate, i want to completely utilize Karate; however difficult that may be... :):)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry XML is not equal to JSON. I'm really not sure what you are trying to do here. Karate is for matching against some expected payload.

Maybe what you need to do is get a sample XML response, convert that to JSON and save that as a file. Then use the `read()` syntax to use THAT in a match - that would make sense.

Comment: Yeah, i need to convert from XML to JSON and print. Thats all i have to do. Ignoring comparing json to xml, how can i convert this and print i json format? Typeconversion doesnt seem to work for me; or that might be a mistake. I can see runner simply skips those 2 line.

Comment: @sandeephegde sorry I can't make out anything at this point - so I have to refer you to these instructions: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Okay, I'll submit with a sample project. BTW, all i need to do is convert my XML response to Json and print it. Thats all!